# Creating a method definition tree from a method symbol and a body

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, scala-2.10, scala-macros

Is there a convenient way to turn a [`MethodSymbol`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$MethodSymbolApi) into the left-hand side of a method definition tree (i.e., a [`DefDef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Trees$DefDefApi)) in Scala 2.10?

For example, suppose I want to create a macro that will take an instance of a trait and wrap all of that trait's methods with some debugging functionality. I can write the following:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object WrapperExample {
  def wrap[A](a: A): A = macro wrap_impl[A]

  def wrap_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(a: c.Expr[A]) = {
    import c.universe._

    val wrapped = weakTypeOf[A]
    val f = Select(reify(Predef).tree, "println")

    val methods = wrapped.declarations.collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol if !m.isConstructor => DefDef(
        Modifiers(Flag.OVERRIDE),
        m.name,
        Nil, Nil,
        TypeTree(),
        Block(
          Apply(f, c.literal("Calling: " + m.name.decoded).tree :: Nil),
          Select(a.tree, m.name)
        )
      )
    }.toList

  //...
}
```

I've elided the boring business of sticking these methods in a new anonymous class that implements the trait and then instantiating that class—you can find a complete working example [here](https://gist.github.com/4234441) if you're interested.

Now I can write this, for example:

```
scala> trait X { def foo = 1; def bar = 'a }
defined trait X

scala> val x = new X {}
x: X = $anon$1@15dd533

scala> val w: X = WrapperExample.wrap[X](x)
w: X = $1$$1@27c3a4a3

scala> w.foo
Calling: foo
res0: Int = 1

scala> w.bar
Calling: bar
res1: Symbol = 'a
```

So it works, but only in very simple cases—it won't if the trait has methods with parameter lists, with access modifiers, annotations, etc.

What I really want is a function that will take a method symbol and a tree for the new body and return a `DefDef`. I've started writing one by hand, but it involves a lot of fiddly stuff like this:

```
List(if (method.isImplicit) Some(Flag.IMPLICIT) else None, ...)
```

Which is annoying, verbose, and error-prone. Am I missing some nicer way to do this in the new Reflection API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no standard way to go from a symbol to a defining tree.

Your best bet would probably be to iterate through `c.enclosingRun.units`, recursing into each of the `unit.body` trees as you go. If you see a `DefDef`, which has a `symbol` equal to your symbol, then you've reached your destination. upd. Don't forget to `duplicate` the defining tree before reusing it!

This technique is far from being the most convenient thing in the world, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks (and +1), but what if the trait I'm looking to wrap is from a library? In that case I'm stuck with the approach above, right?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. You can use this API: https://github.com/scalamacros/kepler/blob/0acb8a30c379f268e8a3e1340504530493a1a1dc/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Trees.scala#L2480. We deprecated it in 2.10.1, but you can take a look at how it's implemented: https://github.com/scalamacros/kepler/blob/0acb8a30c379f268e8a3e1340504530493a1a1dc/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Trees.scala#L975.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following. This works with multiple parameters and curried functions and type parameters ;)

```
val methods = wrapped.declarations.collect {
  case m: MethodSymbol if !m.isConstructor => DefDef(
    Modifiers(Flag.OVERRIDE),
    m.name,
    m.typeParams.map(TypeDef(_)),
    m.paramss.map(_.map(ValDef(_))),
    TypeTree(m.returnType),
    Block(
      Apply(f, c.literal("Calling: " + m.name.decoded).tree :: Nil),
      m.paramss.foldLeft(Select(a.tree.duplicate, m.name): Tree)((prev, params) =>
        Apply(prev, params.map(p => Ident(p.name)))
      )
    )
  )
}.toList
```

Comment: There's also `DefDef(sym, tree)` which does the same, but as it's been mentioned below this method has just been deprecated along with `TypeDef(sym)` and `ValDef(sym)`. upd. It doesn't do the same, because your code seems to omit existing modifiers.

Comment: Also see my comments to the OP's gist: https://gist.github.com/4234441. Your code has the same subtle problem as that code does.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I updated my answer accordingly. This may explain some issues I have on some of my macros with nasty compiler crashes.